# Initializer of subclass of UIPageViewController not accessible

Tags: swift, initialization, uipageviewcontroller

I made a subclass of `UIPageViewController`:

```
public class MilestonesPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {}
```

In this class I did not override any initializer. When I am trying to create new instance of `MilestonesPageViewController` it does not allow me to use `(transitionStyle: navigationOrientation: options:)` initializer, only `()` and `(nibName: bundle:)` ones.

Can someone explain me, why is that initializer not accessible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind showing your code?

Comment: What part of the code would you like to see? I don't mind posting it but it is really extensive. I don't understand what could influence this behavior. Subclass inherits from superclass and it doesn't implement any of its initializers, therefore it should inherit all of its initializers (if I understand apple documentation correctly)..